# manifest for bitwarden/self-host:beta not found

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I can't figure out why simple command to pull docker image for self-host bitwarden results in error:

Command:
`docker pull bitwarden/self-host:beta`

Result:
`Error response from daemon: manifest for bitwarden/self-host:beta not found`

Update (Feb-4-2023):
Looks like the issue is spreading, now I can't pull `parseplatform/parse-server:latest`, however I can pull `parseplatform/parse-server:5.4.0` - which was pushed 4 month ago.

Comment: Does that happen with all images, or specifically the `bitwarden/self-host` image?

Comment: specifically with bitwarden/self-host
I tried others within bitwarden and they pull no problem

Comment: I think I have the same issue, it seems that older docker versions can no longer pull some images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384648/pull-from-docker-hub-returns-not-found-with-older-docker-version