# Pull from docker hub returns not found with older docker version

Tags: docker

I have a server with the old version of docker `17.06.1-ce` and I've noticed that some images (built and pushed via new docker and `docker buildx`) cannot be pulled with the error, e.g.:

```
Error response from daemon: manifest for wodby/mariadb:10.3-3.24.0 not found
```

The image with this tag can be found on docker hub and docker pull works fine with newer docker.

The login to docker hub doesn't affect anything. I use the same architecture `linux/amd64` on servers where it works and doesn't work.

Is this a known behaviour? Is there a way workaround for this? I guess the reason could be the deprecation of the old docker hub api.

UPD: according to https://www.docker.com/blog/registry-v1-api-deprecation/ docker 17.03+ are compatible with v2 registry API and should be working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issued caused by buildx version. I use GitHub Actions (`docker/setup-buildx-action`) to build images include the one that cannot be pulled. GitHub Actions has recently upgraded their build OS from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS and with it they upgraded buildx from 0.9.1 to 0.10.0 and since then pull has stopped working. Most likely caused by SLSA provenance attestation https://github.com/docker/buildx/releases/tag/v0.10.0

I've resolved the pull issue by upgrading docker to at least 18.06+.

Ref https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-17-06-pull-returns-not-found-for-existing-image/134524/3

Comment: Thank you !

This information was very hard to find. Sometimes when people deprecate stuff and knowingly break working configurations, they hide this fact the best they can instead of informing about the caveats of updating. Downgrading setup-buildx-action to `v0.9.1` and the runner to `ubuntu-20.04` lets you make working images again.